# Mulesoft - Export Log To AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, mulesoft, cloudhub

I am planning to export logging from MuleSoft CloudHub to AWS CloudWatch.

I saw there is one AWS CloudWatch Connector in GitHub:
https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/mule-amazon-cloudwatch-connector/tree/master/mule-cloudwatch-connector

Is there any examples on how to implement this?

And which AWS CloudWatch features is supported in this connector?

I found other export logs method with examples, but not for AWS CloudWatch:
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXUALSA4/export-log-to-external-system

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create  a Mule application that reads logs from CloudHub using [CloudHub's API](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/) and pushes them to CloudWatch. The readme for the connector doesn't seem to mention an operation to put logs into CloudWatch, but if CloudWatch has a REST API for it -every AWS product has it- you could use it in your application.

This KB article shows how to get the logs from CloudHub: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-get-whole-Application-logs-from-Cloudhub-through-API

Comment: Thanks for the info. You try to setup this whole flow before?

Comment: Only the CloudHub API part, by following the instructions in the article.